# Angular Tour of Heroes: why are there javascript files?

Tags: angular

I started through the tutorial with some seed project, like my-app or something, apparently not the recommended approach, but it was working for a while, up until Step 6 of the tutorial, where you remove style info to a separate file. So I grabbed the .zip that's provided at the end of Step 6, unzipped it, ran "npm install" and then "npm start".

Needless to say, my problems with the css stuff were solved, but I noticed a curious thing: for some reason javascript files were created in the new project (the one I downloaded) and not in the one that I built by working through the tutorial. Why would javascript files be created?

Comment: what javascript files?

Comment: These java script files are the compiled ts files at the end when your angular project is compiled it is compiled to js files which is rendered , browsers dont understand ts , its only for ease of development and strong typing